# What means this JMS configuration into a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jms, spring-jms

I am studying how Spring framework handle JMS and I have the following doubt related this question founded on my study material.

Consider the following JMS configuration defined into a Spring application:

```
<jms:listener-container connetionFactory="connectionFactory">
    <jms:listener-destination="order.queue" ref="orderListener" method="order" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

What exactly does this configuration?

Now I know that a **JMS connection** is tipically obtained from a **factory**, so I think that it is configuring the factory that give me my JMS connection (is it right?)

But what exactly specify this line?:

```
<jms:listener-destination="order.queue" ref="orderListener" method="order" />
```

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a Message-driven Bean-like in the *plain* Java EE world. Have a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace). By the way, the attribute is `destination="queue.name"`; there is no such a thing like `<jms:listener-destination="order.queue"...`

- **destination:** The destination name for this listener (in other words: the queue where the listener will "listen" to; named as *destination* in newer versions of Spring)
- **ref:** The bean name of the handler (see next point)
- **method:** The name of the handler method to invoke. If the `ref` points to a `MessageListener` or Spring `SessionAwareMessageListener`, this attribute may be omitted (this is why the latter two must implements the `onMessage` method, and by convention this will be called)